# passing data from a chef databag to java from jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, chef-infra, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

## necessity

bvt tests against infrastructure using java. we have several systems that have rest endpoints. ie vmware, control m, ec2, kubernetes, oracle cloud, gcp

### prereqs

- secrets never touch file system unencrypted
- secrets never hit logs unencrypted

### setup:

- chef server
- jenkins
- jenkinsfile job (groovy)
- java package (custom) that talks to 3rd party apis and performs bvts
- 2 separate teams on different sprint schedules

### problem

passing secrets from jenkins that has secrets decrypted (ie console creds to vmware cluster) from chef server. i have tried the following:

1. `mvn:dependency copy`, this is fine, but how to pass a password
   when invoking the jar?
2. `grapes grab` and invoke directly from code. works locally, but jenkins errors out with 'no suitable classloader found for grab'. the way to get around this is to put that code ibto a separate file and use an bash to invoke. im back to passing credentials

## ask

- what is the recommended process?

## comment rollups

- we are unable to modify the chef or jenkins setups

## solved

- moved the grab call to an external groovy file, calling with sh pipeline step. this is necessary because jenkins dependencies were breaking our integration. using the sh step gets a fresh java vm

Comment: switching the chef/jenkins part of the setup is not an option.

Comment: I think we're going to need more info about what you're actually doing if you're going to get a good answer. This is currently an architecture level question that requires some pretty good knowledge of your specific circumstances to answer with any accuracy.

Comment: IIUC, you store your secrets in encrypted data bags and want to load them in Jenkins Pipeline and pass them to jar as arguments.
If so:
1. Run [knife solo data bag](https://github.com/thbishop/knife-solo_data_bag) from Pipeline
2. Parse its output as JSON
3. Pass secrets to jar via environment variables